# Prove infinite set has cardinality greater or equal to $\mathbb{N}$ without axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are two related posts but I didn't see the satisfied answer there:

1. [Infinite Set has greater or equal cardinality that of N](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917593/infinite-set-has-greater-or-equal-cardinality-that-of-n)
2. [How can I prove that the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ is infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132308/how-can-i-prove-that-the-set-of-natural-numbers-mathbb-n-is-infinite)

My question is how to prove infinite set has cardinality greater or equal to $\mathbb{N}$ without axiom of choice, and for generality without using contradiction?

Since $\mathbb{N}$ was constructed through the inductive sets, I can hardly see a direct construction of a function $f$.

The possible solution I have right now seemed to be using the recursion theorem and define $g(f_n,n)$ to be the elements of $B-\{f_0,...,f_n\}$, but this seem to be impossible without AC.

Another way I thought about is argue that one can pick a sequence $b_0,...,$, such that $b_i\neq b_j$ for $i\neq j$. The sequence won't end other wise $B$ will be finite. But this required the usage of contradiction.

How to ptove the theorem without axiom of choice and the usage of contradiction?

Comment: How do you define a set to be infinite?

Comment: @LeAnhDung the standard definition from Introduction to set thoery. $\mathbb{N}=\{ x|x\in I $ for every inductive set $ I \}$.

Comment: No, I meant $X$ is infinite $\iff\cdots$

Comment: @LeAnhDung If $X$ is not finite, then $X$ is infinite, so there is no bijection between $X$ and any elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank your for your clarification! I got it.

Comment: It can't be done. You need the axiom of choice to prove that every infinite set is greater than or equal to $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be proved without the axiom of choice. Or, more precisely, it cannot be proved in ZF alone.

It is known to be consistent with ZF that an [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) exists -- meaning an infinite set that is not the disjoint union of two infinite sets. Such a set would be an infinite set whose cardinality is *incomparable* with that of $\mathbb N$ and therefore be a counterexample to the claim.

(You don't need the *full* axiom of choice, though. The naive pick-a-sequence argument will go through with the axiom of *dependent* choice, and even the axiom of *countable* choice is enough, with a slightly more involved argument).